# postgres regexp_replace want to allow only a-z and A-Z

Tags: regex, postgresql

In a table column in string we can have numbers/special chars/white spaces.
I want to replace numbers/special chars/white space with empty char, i see there is function named `regexp_replace` but how to use not much user friendly help avaialble for example i want to use following string.

```
String = 'abc$wanto&toremove#special~chars'
```

I want to remove all special chars and numbers from above string want to allow only `a-z` and `A-Z` rest of chars should be replaced with `''` how to do that ?

Answer (score 74, accepted):

```
SELECT regexp_replace('abc$wanto&toremove#special~chars', '[^a-zA-Z]', '', 'g');

        regexp_replace        
------------------------------
 abcwantotoremovespecialchars
```

Answer (score 15):

For me the following worked.

```
regexp_replace(code, '[^a-zA-Z0-9]+', '','g')
```

As it adds global filter so it repeats the regex for the entire string.

Example,

```
SELECT regexp_replace('Well- This Did-Not work&*($%%)_', '[^a-zA-Z0-9]+', '')
```

Returns: "WellThis Did-Not work&*($%%)_"

```
SELECT regexp_replace('Well- This Did-Not work&*($%%)_', '[^a-zA-Z0-9]+', '','g')
```

Returns: "WellThisDidNotwork"

Which has the characters we don't want removed.

Comment: what is the use of g in above expression can you pls tell me

Comment: It is a global modifier.
"g is for global search. Meaning it'll match all occurrences. "

Explained here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12993629/what-is-the-meaning-of-the-g-flag-in-regular-expressions

Comment: Thanks. Was looking for something to remove whitespace but couldn't accomplish it by specifying the whitespace types. Using an inverted match against alphanumeric characters is much easier (so long as you don't have special characters you want to keep).

Answer (score 11):

To make it simpler:

```
regexp_replace('abc$wanto&toremove#special~chars', '[^[:alpha:]]')
```

Comment: this works, though for some reason seems to be absent from [the docs](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/functions-matching.html#POSIX-CLASS-SHORTHAND-ESCAPES-TABLE)

Comment: `select regexp_replace('abc$wanto&toremove#special~chars', '[^[:alpha:]]', '', 'g')`

Answer (score 5):

If you want to replace the char with the closest not special char, you can do something like this:

```
select
  translate(
    lower( name ), ' ''àáâãäéèëêíìïîóòõöôúùüûçÇ', '--aaaaaeeeeiiiiooooouuuucc'
  ) as new_name,
  name
from cities;
```

Answer (score 0):

Should be:

```
regexp_replace('abc$wanto&toremove#special~chars', '[^a-zA-Z]+', '')
```

Comment: it wont work try by yoursef
select regexp_replace('abc123', 'a-zA-Z', '')

Comment: Sorry I missed the brackets, and unfortunately I cant test it for the moment