# What is the meaning of the 'g' flag in regular expressions?

Tags: javascript, regex

What is the meaning of the `g` flag in regular expressions?

What is is the difference between `/.+/g` and `/.+/`?

Answer (score 195, accepted):

`g` is for global search. Meaning it'll match all occurrences. You'll usually also see `i` which means ignore case.

Reference: [global - JavaScript | MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/global)

> The "g" flag indicates that the regular expression should be tested against all possible matches in a string.

Without the `g` flag, it'll only test for the first.

Additionally, make sure to check [cchamberlain's answer below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45528278/1029146) for details on how it sets the `lastIndex` property, which can cause unexpected side effects when re-using a regex against a series of values.

Comment: So the /g flag is irrelevant when using the .test function, because it only finds the first match anyway, right?

Comment: @xr280xr Not irrelevant, more like counterproductive. It will break things if you re-use the RegExp. `var r = /a/g; console.log(r.test('a'), r.test('a')); // true false`

Answer (score 67):

Example in Javascript to explain:

```
> 'aaa'.match(/a/g)
[ 'a', 'a', 'a' ]

> 'aaa'.match(/a/)
[ 'a', index: 0, input: 'aaa' ]
```

Comment: Thanks. I wasn't sure if regex in Javascript could return an array like it does in PHP, this confirms it.

Answer (score 20):

As @matiska pointed out, the `g` flag sets the `lastIndex` property as well.

A very important side effect of this is if you are reusing the same regex instance against a matching string, it will eventually fail because it only starts searching at the `lastIndex`.

```js
// regular regex
const regex = /foo/;

// same regex with global flag
const regexG = /foo/g;

const str = " foo foo foo ";

const test = (r) => console.log(
    r,
    r.lastIndex,
    r.test(str),
    r.lastIndex
);

// Test the normal one 4 times (success)
test(regex);
test(regex);
test(regex);
test(regex);

// Test the global one 4 times
// (3 passes and a fail)
test(regexG);
test(regexG);
test(regexG);
test(regexG);
```

Comment: After spending 3 hours on the bug, I stumbled upon this answer. I had used `/g` flag which was skipping few occurrences of the pattern because it was always moving forward. You saved my day. Thanks!

Answer (score 17):

`g` is the global search flag.

The global search flag makes the RegExp search for a pattern throughout the string, creating an array of all occurrences it can find matching the given pattern.

So the difference between  `/.+/g` and `/.+/`  is that the `g` version will find every occurrence instead of just the first.

Answer (score 12):

There is no difference between `/.+/g` and `/.+/` because they will both only ever match the whole string once. The `g` makes a difference if the regular expression could match more than once or contains groups, in which case `.match()` will return an array of the matches instead of an array of the groups.

Answer (score 10):

1. `g` `->` returns all matches
2. `without g` `->` returns first match

example:

1. `'1 2 1 5 6  7'.match(/\d+/)` returns `["1", index: 0, input: "1 2 1 5 6  7", groups: undefined]`. As you see we can only take first match `"1"`.
2. `'1 2 1 5 6  7'.match(/\d+/g)` returns an array of all matches `["1", "2", "1", "5", "6", "7"]`.

Answer (score 9):

Beside already mentioned meaning of `g` flag, it influences `regexp.lastIndex` property:

> The lastIndex is a read/write integer property of regular expression
>   instances that specifies the index at which to start the next match. 
>   (...) This property is set only if the regular expression instance
>   used the "g" flag to indicate a global search.

Reference: [Mozilla Developer Network](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/lastIndex)

Answer (score 3):

G in regular expressions is a defines a global search, meaning that it would search for all the instances on all the lines.

Answer (score 3):

Will give example based on string. If we want to remove all occurences from a
string. 
Lets say if we want to remove all occurences of "o" with "" from "hello world"

```
"hello world".replace(/o/g,'');
```

Answer (score 2):

In my case i have a problem that i need to reevaluate string each time from the first letter, for this a have to remove `/my_regexp/`**g**(global flag) to stop moving *lastIndex*.

as mentioned in mdn:

> Be sure that the global (g) flag is set, or lastIndex will never be advanced.
> https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/exec#specifications

Answer (score 0):

Maybe some of you are here because your regex instance set with the `g` flag failed when it shouldn't.

Here is an example: You want to find all the strings in an array that contains the letter "a".

```js
const array = ["today", "cat", "dog", "rabbit"]
const reg = new RegExp("a", "g")
const matchedArray = array.filter(v => {
  const matched = reg.test(v)
  console.log(`String "${v}", matched: ${matched}`)
})
```

You'll find that strings `rabit` and `today` pass the test, but `cat` doesn't.

That's because after matching `today` successfully, the `lastIndex` property of the regex instance is set to the end of the `today` string, which is 4.

Then the regex instance tests `cat`. Because there's no `a` character from index 4, the test fails, and `lastIndex` is set to 0.

Next, `dog` faills the test and `lastIndex` is set to 0 again. Then `rabbit` is tested starting from index 0. It passes.

So the bottom line is: Be careful if you add the `g` flag to your regex instance and you try to call it with `exec` or `test` multiple times.