# How can I add some text before each vowel? (Code stops after first one)

Tags: javascript

I want any input text to have the word "vowel" added before each vowel - e.g. "Hello world" becomes "Hvowelellvowelo wvowelorld"

At the moment my code works but only for the first vowel and then stops - how can I set it to repeat across the whole text input?

http://jsfiddle.net/53qH6/5/

```
document.getElementById("input").addEventListener("keyup", function() {
document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = this.value.replace(/([aeiou]).*/i, "vowel$1");
}, false);
```

Thanks.

Comment: add the `g` flag to the regex.

Comment: Plz Refer this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12993629/the-g-flag-in-regular-expressions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
document.getElementById("input").addEventListener("keyup", function() {
    document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = this.value.replace(/([aeiou])/ig, "vowel$1");
}, false);
```

This will solve your problem

Fiddle :

http://jsfiddle.net/sornalingam/53qH6/6/

The g means Global, and causes the replace call to replace all matches, not just the first one

[The 'g' flag in regular expressions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12993629/the-g-flag-in-regular-expressions)

Comment: Down voting with out comment is pet peeve of mine

Comment: And the one Who downvoted plz check the fiddle and let me Know

Comment: i mean in your answer - your answer is just code. that's why i down voted.

Comment: @DanielA.White  I have added the explanation. I hope now you can upvote :) lol