# Replacing vowels in a string with "i"...could you please explain this expression? someText.replace(/[aAeEoOuU]/ig,"i")

Tags: javascript, replace

Below is the complete code which will change any vowel in the user's input to an "i". Just curious to what the characters mean in the expression?

- what is the difference between using a `/` and `"`.
- What does the `ig` mean.

```
var someText = prompt("What is Lance trying to say?");      
var noVowels = someText.replace(/[aAeEoOuU]/ig,"i");      
console.log (noVowels);
```

Comment: `ig` are regex flags. g stands for global, i for case insensitive - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12993629/the-g-flag-in-regular-expressions

Comment: if the i in ig stands for case insensitive, why do I need to include both the lowercase and uppercase variations of the vowel I'm replaing

Comment: @user3715006  You don't have to!

Comment: @undone You're right I don't! Thanks alot :)

Comment: Pick up a basic regexp tutorial and go through it. By the way, do you want upper-case `I` to be replaced with lower-case `i`? Then you'll need to fix your regexp.

Answer (score 1):

The characters inside the square brackets is the character set (vowels) that is being replaced.
A regular expression such as this should be placed between //
What follows these slashes are some options: 
i - case insensitive

g - global match