# how to repeat the regular expression

Tags: jquery

i have written a regular expression to get the input as for eg: `a3f=h6df&gd5t=shyc5`

but my code is getting only for first one after it is not checking for second one
my code is `/^[0-9a-zA-Z]+=[0-9a-zA-Z]+$/`

Help me with the regular expression which checks for whole inputs. It should repeats for many times based on input

Comment: /^[0-9a-zA-Z]+=[0-9a-zA-Z]+$/g ....g -  global flag...

Comment: glabal flag didnt work in my situation

Answer (score 2):

Add global modifier ([w3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_regexp_g.asp)) for a global search:

```
var result = str.match(/^[0-9a-zA-Z]+=[0-9a-zA-Z]+$/g);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add a global flag to it: `/^[0-9a-zA-Z]+=[0-9a-zA-Z]+$/g` - [see this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12993629/the-g-flag-in-regular-expressions) and [this reference](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_regexp_g.asp)

Comment: Can you provide an example of the actual code that you're using? With this sort of issue you might need to iterate through the results and so on

Answer (score 0):

If your String is separated by ampersand (&):

Try This:

```
/(^|&)[0-9a-zA-Z]+=[0-9a-zA-Z]+/g
```

[test Link 1](https://regex101.com/r/sJ3nQ3/4)

Comment: But now i got a new problem. This [0-9a-zA-Z] condition is not working properly.. everything is accepting