# Javascript match returns only first match

Tags: javascript, regex

I am having problems to get the matches to a simple regex. Here is the code:

```
var keyWordRegex = /\{\w+\}/;
"idSalaVirtual={idSalaVirtual}&idSalaVirtualOferta={idSalaVirtualOferta}".match(keyWordRegex)
```

This code returns `["{idSalaVirtual}"] instead of ["{idSalaVirtual}", "{idSalaVirtualOferta}"]` that was the result I was specting. If I remove {idSalaVirtual} from the test string, then it returns `["{idSalaVirtualOferta}"]`.

Does anyone know why it is not returning the two words from the method?

Thanks in advance.

The problem was solved using the 'g' flag, but I didn't even know the existance of this flag. So there is no reason the mark it as duplicate of  [The 'g' flag in regular expressions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12993629/the-g-flag-in-regular-expressions)
If someone goes through the same problem that I did without knowing the existance of the 'g' flag, they won't find an answer.

Comment: Does `/....regex..../g` work?  You'd need to make it greedy to find all the following matches.

Comment: Yes, it does. Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `g` flag

```
var keyWordRegex = /\{\w+\}/g;
  "idSalaVirtual={idSalaVirtual}&idSalaVirtualOferta={idSalaVirtualOferta}".match(keyWordRegex)
```

Comment: Yes, it worked. Thank you very much