# Regex find ALL patterns between string

Tags: python, regex, string, digits

I want to match digits betwen "000" or betwen \b and "000" or "000" and \b from a string like this:

```
11101110001011101000000011101010111
```

I have tried with expressions like this:

```
(?<=000)\d+(?=000)
```

but I only get the largest occurrence

I expect to get:

```
1110111
1011101
0
11101010111
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [The 'g' flag in regular expressions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12993629/the-g-flag-in-regular-expressions)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [`regex` package](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/regex) and the `.findall()` method:

```
In [1]: s = "11101110001011101000000011101010111"

In [2]: import regex

In [3]: regex.findall(r"(?<=000|^)\d+?(?=000|$)", s)
Out[3]: ['1110111', '1011101', '0', '00011101010111']
```

The `000|^` and `000|$` would help to match either the `000` or the beginning and the end of a string respectively. Also note the `?` after the `\d+` - we are making it [*non-greedy*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2301285/what-do-lazy-and-greedy-mean-in-the-context-of-regular-expressions).

Note that the regular `re.findall()` would fail with the following error in this case:

> error: look-behind requires fixed-width pattern

This is because `re` does not support *variable-length lookarounds* but `regex` does.

Comment: It didn't work, I tried this `(?<=000)[^0]\d+?(?=000|\b)|(?<=\b)[^0]\d+?(?=000|\b)` but now it doesn't get the 0 betwen "000" and "000"

Comment: I have solved!! Thanks, this is the code that works
`(?<=000)[^0]\d+?(?=000|\b)|(?<=\b)[^0]\d+?(?=000|\b)|(?<=000)\d(?=000)`

Answer (score 1):

you can do it with the re module like this:

```
re.findall(r'(?:\b|(?<=000))(\d+?)(?:000|\b)', s)
```