# How to use "RegExp.exec" in TypeScript?

Tags: typescript

I want to use the method "exec" in RegExp. I write below code to try to do:

```
let result = <RegExpExecArray>{};
while (result = expressionCheck.exec(text)) {
    let matchIndex = result.index;
    let t = result[0].length;
    matchRanges.push(new RegRange(matchIndex, t));
}
```

But it throws error about:

```
Build:Type 'RegExpExecArray | null' is not assignable to type 'RegExpExecArray'.
```

I try to modify the loop condition to :

```
while ((result = expressionCheck.exec(text)) != null) {
```

It still doesn't work. So how to write the loop condition for this case?

Comment: Did you try `let result: RegExpExecArray | null;`? Or just leave out the type altogether, and let TS figure it out.

Answer (score 8):

You need to write it like this:

```
let result;
while ((result = expression.exec(text)) !== null) {
    let matchIndex = result.index;
    let t = result[0].length;
    matchRanges.push(new RegRange(matchIndex, t));
}
```

Why the original does not work:
The original code declared `result` to be of type `RegExpExecArray`. This type is not compatible with the return type of `exec` which is `RegExpExecArray | null`. In spite of the narrowing, via `!== null`, the code will still assign `null` to `result`. That is why it is an error.

You can also write it in the following fashion.

```
for (let result = expression.exec(text); result !== null; result = expression.exec(text)) {
  const matchIndex = result.index;
  const t = result[0].length;
  matchRanges.push(new RegRange(matchIndex, t));
}
```

Comment: Yes, this style should work. Is this only way to make it work in ts?

Comment: You could use a while loop but then you would have to write `result = expression.exec(text);` twice, once inside the loop, and once outside. Also, this way you can remove the ugly type assertion and can keep `result` scoped to the loop. If you just want all matches, why not use the `/g` flag and skip a loop entirely?

Comment: I just want all matches, could you give more detail for using /g flag? Thanks

Comment: Sure, but it is really off topic.

Comment: This should explain it http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12993629/the-g-flag-in-regular-expressions

Comment: You're not giving TS enough credit. Believe me, an extra set of parens is definitely not enough to confuse it or prevent it from doing flow control analysis.

Answer (score 2):

I found `String.prototype.matchAll` much more readable, because I can destructure it:

```
const [[group1, group2]] = [...text.matchAll(expressionCheck)];
```

[MDN recommends it as an alternative](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/exec) and [here are the docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/matchAll).

Answer (score 1):

I wanted to capture hours and minutes from below string

> 18h:20m

So, I used following expression

```
const [, hours, minutes] = /^(\d+)[:h -]\s?(\d+)m?$/.exec(string) || ['', '', ''];
```

You can customize it based on the number of matches you are capturing.

Note: exec() will return all your matches as string type.