# preg_match: between string and first non-alpha numeric character

Tags: php, regex

I'm trying to extract text between a given string and first non-alpha numeric character. The code below works but it's using the  tag instead of \W.

```
$my_string = 'Auth code: 02452A</div>';
preg_match("~Auth code:(.*)</div>~",$my_string, $m);
print_r($m);
// shouldn't this work, too?
preg_match("~Auth code:(.*)\W~",$my_string, $m);
```

Comment: Not a duplicate of what you indicate @Wiktor.
@Banditvibe, You can just add g flag : `preg_match("~Auth code:(.*)\W~g",$my_string, $m);` : see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12993629/what-is-the-meaning-of-the-g-flag-in-regular-expressions

Comment: @PierreGranger: Ok, might not be a dupe. Still, it is PHP and not JS. `g` modifier is not supported, to get multiple matches in PHP, you need to use `preg_match_all`. I think `preg_match("~Auth code:\s*(.*?)\W~",$my_string, $m);` will work, but `"~Auth code:\s*\K\w+~"` is much better. See [**this IDEONE demo**](http://ideone.com/jVqRS5).

Comment: @PierreGranger Ok, preg_match_all for global

Comment: @Banditvibe Is http://ideone.com/jVqRS5 what you need?

Comment: Well i can't explain why but `preg_match("~Auth code:(.*)\W~g",$my_string, $m);` works for me... `Array
(
    [0] => Auth code: 02452A
    [1] =>  02452A
)`

Comment: @PierreGranger: see [this demo](http://ideone.com/DbDeTJ): *PHP Warning:  preg_match(): Unknown modifier 'g'* and `$m` is empty.

Comment: @wiktor-stribiżew yes, perfect. Like the \K

Comment: Yeah i've seen the warning, its just funny how it works even with the warning. Probably more a bug than anyting, but still funny :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `Auth code:(.*)</div>` pattern matches `Auth code:` literal substring, then matches and captures into Group 1 any 0+ chars other than line break chars, *as many as possible* as the `*` is a *greedy* quantifier, and then matches `</div>`, an obligatory literal substring.

If you replace `.*` with `.*?` (a lazy version), you still won't get the result you need because there is a space after `:`, and `\W` matches a space. So, `.*?` will match an empty string between `:` and the space.

The best way to get the substring you need is to add `\s*` (any 0+ whitespaces) after `:` and then use a *match reset operator* `\K` that omits the text matched so far, and match 1 or more word chars (it is much more efficient than match any chars lazily up to the first non-word char):

```
~Auth code:\s*\K\w+~
```

**Details**:

- `Auth code:` - a literal substring
- `\s*` - 0+ whitespaces
- `\K` - a match reset operator
- `\w+` - 1 or more word chars

See the [PHP demo online](http://ideone.com/jVqRS5):

```
$my_string = 'Auth code: 02452A</div>';
preg_match("~Auth code:\s*\K\w+~",$my_string, $m);
print_r($m[0]); // => 02452A
```