# Override jQuery function in other web pages

Tags: jquery

I have a website with multiple pages. I have a logo in the navbar that is actually an h1 which I had **altered in the homepage** with jQuery with the following code to have the first letter of each word with a different style.

```
var words = $('h1').text().split(' ');
var html = '';
$.each(words, function() {
    html += '<span style="font-size:120%;color:#1AC4F8;">'+this.substring(0,1)+'</span>'+this.substring(1) + ' ';
});
$('#logo h1').html(html);
```

**In the other pages I want the logo to be an h2**, having the same style and size as the h1 in the homepage.

I tried creating two different functions for h1 and h2, even I created a js file with the same function, but instead selecting h2, and tried to override the first one. But with no success. Maybe you can do this in the same function with "if"?

I hope you can achieve this without having to create a js file with only this function to aim at the homepage and another one to the rest of the other web pages. I would like to do it as most professionally as possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of targetting `h1` or `h2`, use a CSS class name for this:

In your HTML you would add the attribute `class="style-first-letters"` to either the `h1` or `h2` element, depending on the page.

Then the code would be more generic and use this selector:

```
$('.style-first-letters')
```

I would also suggest using a CSS style class for the first letter style, instead of using the `style` attribute, and use `replace` to perform the insertion of the `span` tags:

```js
$(function () {
    $h = $(".style-first-letters");
    $h.html($h.text().replace(/(^|\s)(\S)/g, function(m, space, ch) {
        return `${space}<span class="first-letter">${ch}</span>`;
    }));
});
```

```css
.first-letter {
  font-size:120%;
  color:#1AC4F8;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h1 class="style-first-letters">Style the First Letters</h1>
```

#### Explanation of the function

First the collection of elements that have class `style-first-letters` is stored in `$h`. Note that the class name must be prefixed with a dot. In your case that jQuery collection would represent the one element you want to process.

Then [`replace`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) is called on the text retrieved with `$h.text()`. The function `replace` can take a [regular expression](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions) as first argument, which has its own syntax:

```
/(^|\s)(\S)/g
```

The `/` is the delimiter by which JavaScript sees it is a regular expression literal. The [`g`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12993629/what-is-the-meaning-of-the-g-flag-in-regular-expressions) at the end is a modifier that indicates the replacement must be applied to all occurrences (**g**lobal). Then we have two parts:

- `(^|\s)`: the `\s` represents any white space character, like space, newline, non-breaking space, ... As the very first character of the text is not preceded by a space, there is another option for this match: `^`. The caret denotes the start of the string that is being searched. The pipe (`|`) is a logical OR operator. So we have: find the start of the string or else a space. The parentheses have to functions:

  - to specify the scope of the OR operator
  - to capture the character that is matched (the space) for later reference
- `(\S)`: the `\S` is the opposite of `\s`: it matches any non-space character. Since this follows either the start of the string or a space, this means we are matching with the first letter of a word here. Again the parentheses allow us to determine what that character is

The second argument to `replace` tells it what the replacement should be for each found match. Usually you would specify a string literal there, but you can also provide a callback function. The `replace` implementation will call that callback function for every match, and pass the matched string as first argument to that function. If there are capture groups (parentheses), then the strings that were matched by them (during one match) are passed as additional arguments to that function. Since we have two such capture groups, we can expect three arguments are passed to the callback function:
  * `m` the complete match: a space (or empty string) and a non-space
  * `space`: the space character or empty string
  * `ch`: the character that must be formatted

The return value of that function will be used by the `replace` implementation to make the actual replacement.

The return value is a [template literal](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals), recognisable by the back quotes. This is just a fancy way to build a string from variables:

```
return `${space}<span class="first-letter">${ch}</span>`;
```

It returns the same value as this:

```
return space + '<span class="first-letter">' + ch + '</span>';
```

So this value just repeats whatever `space` is (nothing or a white space), followed by the `span`. As this function is called for all matches, all occurrences of first letters are thus replaced with `span` tags.

Finally the result of the `replace` operation is immediately passed on to the jQuery `html` method, replacing the content of the targetted element `$h`.

Comment: Thank you it works perfectly, but I would like to understand the function you created here, I'm afraid I'm quite new on jQuery. Could you explain it to me or at least refer me to some documentation where I can go to?

Comment: I have added some explanations to my answers. The hyperlinks on some key terms should help you find more information.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve it by **Get page name** using following Jquery function

```
    var PageName=location.pathname.split('/').slice(-1)[0]
    if(PageName==='YourHtmlHomePage')
    {
    $('#logo h1').addclass('FirstLetterCapital');
    }
    else
    {  
    $('#logo h1').removeClass('FirstLetterCapital');
    }
```

And by CSS

```
     .FirstLetterCapital::first-letter
      {
          text-transform: capitalize;
          font-size:120%;
          color:#1AC4F8;
      }
```

Comment: Hi, is a bit more complicated than that. The h1 (or h2 in other web pages) is more than 1 word and I want every first letter of each word to have this style. That's why I used Javascript in the first place.