# Capture anything between first [] not all the [] in string

Tags: regex

I have a string like `[only this] i want [to] [capture]`.

I want to have `only this`. I have tried `\[.*?\]` regex but i have the following output:

```
"only this to capture"
```

And is it also possible to only capture anything between second `[]` like `to` in this case.

Comment: What language/tool are you using?

Comment: Are you using [`g` modifier](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12993629)? Or some method that searches for multiple occurrences of a pattern (like `Regex.Matches` in C#, `String#scan()` in Ruby, `re.findall()` in Python...)?

Comment: I am doing it in javascript. I have used g modifier

Comment: I have tried using "y" modifier and it only returns me the first match. But is it possible to get anything between the 2nd or 3rd []?

Answer (score 0):

A bit unclear exactly what you're after, but the following regex captures the word `to` in your example.

```
\[.*?\].*?\[(.*?)\].*?\[.*?\]
```

Please see the following [regexr](https://regexr.com/48iko) for explanation.