# Question about the extent of functionality for the .replace function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, replace, numbers

I am rather new to Javascript and this in general.  After looking for awhile I have been unable to find the answer to my question or maybe I was simply searching the wrong thing.

In a class we were asked to write something where the user could input a number and receive a display of the number back and all numbers leading up to that.  The other portion of this was to replace all instances of numbers containing a number like 5 or 8 with a word.

But
My question was if I could achieve the same ability with the Replace function.

Something like below but if the user displayed 50,51,52 it would say Hello, Hello, Hello instead of Hello0, Hello1, Hello2.

> $(this).html($(this).html().replace(/5/g, "Hello"));

The original assignment was achieved using a few else if statements.  I could also mimic the desired goal above by just writing out tons of variations of the above but that is hardly practical.

> $(this).html($(this).html().replace(/5/g, "Hello"));

Comment: I'm having a hard time understanding the requirements. please show some example inputs & desired outputs. It might also help if you showed your original code with `if`/`else` blocks.

Answer (score 2):

jQuery has a shorthand method of replacing the textContent of an element, and that's [by using a function](http://api.jquery.com/text/#text-function). Perhaps you could use that instead. Then it's just a matter of adjusting your regex to include more than one number (`\d+`) multiple times in the string ([the `g` flag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12993629/what-is-the-meaning-of-the-g-flag-in-regular-expressions)). I've used `text()` instead of `html()` as they have different uses and the former is better for your use case.

```js
$('div').text(function (i, e) {
  return e.replace(/\d+/g, 'Hello');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>50,51,52</div>
```

If you wanted to add spaces after the commas like in your example maybe approach it differently. Here I split the string into an array using a similar regex, [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) all the matched patterns to the word 'Hello', and then join the array up into a string again.

```js
$('div').text(function (i, e) {
  return e.split(/\d+,/g).map(s => 'Hello').join(', ');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>50,51,52</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe a simple regex involving numbers is what you're after:

```js
$("#numbers").on("click", function() {
  $(this).html($(this).html().replace(/\d{2}/g, "Hello"));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.js"></script>
<p id="numbers">51, 52, 53</p>
<p>Click the above paragraph to see magic!</p>
<sub>One-time magic only</sub>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to replace numbers of any length with one thing you can use a [regular expression](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions) like `/\d+/` which means any number of digits:

```js
let s = "50,51,52"
console.log(s.replace(/\d+/g, "hello"))

// only replace digits -- leaves everything else
let s2 = "500 some txt, 1 other,52 more"
console.log(s2.replace(/\d+/g, "hello"))
```