# Regex expression to match strings after example codes

Tags: regex, vb.net, regex-lookarounds

Hello I'm trying to make regex expression to match text after code example of regex that I have at the moment with sample text.

```
(?<=H\d\d\d)([.*\w\W\n]+)(?=End word)
```

https://regex101.com/r/9SBnH9/2

```
Sample text
Sample text
Sample text
H319 asdkjczixuqweoiurqoiweqwrjasdkjfqwe qweiouqwroiu kjasdkj czkjxklqjwekjiouasdiiaosudou
oiuasodiucxzlkjqweoiu oqiwur H320 asdkqjwe askjdq xzc
H325 asjdhasjd zxcjh
H331+H341+H341 askdjvkjzx qweqrqwoe
End word
Sample text
Sample text
```

This is the sample text and I want expression to start searching for matches after find `H**` code and get the text only when find again `H**` code ignore it and take the text and have example with `H**+H**+H**` or `H**+H**`, but same deal skip `H` codes and get the text only. And search until it finds `End word`. I'm to the point where it start from first `H` code, but then it get all the string and end's on end word you can see that in regex site which I send.

I should get this as result:

> asdkjczixuqweoiurqoiweqwrjasdkjfqwe qweiouqwroiu kjasdkj
> czkjxklqjwekjiouasdiiaosudou oiuasodiucxzlkjqweoiu oqiwur.asdkqjwe
> askjdq xzc.asjdhasjd zxcjh.askdjvkjzx qweqrqwoe

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can match all chars in between that are not directly followed by `H` and 3 digits and assert `End word` at the right at the start of the string.

```
(?<=H\d{3}\b)(?:(?!\+?H\d{3}\b)[\S\s])+(?=[\s\S]*\r?\nEnd word\b)
```

The pattern in parts matches:

- `(?<=H\d{3}\b)` Positive lookbehind, assert `H` and 3 digits directly to the left. The word boundary `\b` prevents a partial match
- `(?:` Non capture group

  - `(?!\+?H\d{3}\b)[\S\s]` Match 1+ times any char (including newlines) that are not directly followed by an optional `+` then `H` and 3 digits
- `)+`  Close non capture group and repeat 1+ times
- `(?=` Positive lookahead, assert to the right

  - `[\s\S]*\r?\nEnd word\b` Match `End word` at the start of the string (or leave out the `^` if it is not at the start)
- `)` Close lookahead

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/pVlpgS/1)

If you also don't want to cross matching `End word`, you can add that to the negative lookahead:

```
(?<=H\d{3}\b)(?:(?!\+?H\d{3}\b|^End word\b)[\S\s])+(?=[\s\S]*\r?\nEnd word\b)
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/mkysEU/1/)

Comment: Hello I tested this , but I get only the first H** code text , but not rest of them.

Comment: @Swapx How are you using the code? Did you enable the multiline flag?

Comment: When I test it out on regex builder it shows all correctly , but when I use it in automation (UiPath) it takes only the first line.

Comment: @Swapx Try it like this `(?m)(?<=H\d{3}\b)(?:(?!\+?H\d{3}\b|^End word\b)[\S\s])+(?=[\s\S]*\r?\nEnd word\b)` or `(?m)(?<=H\d{3}\b)(?:(?!\+?H\d{3}\b|^End word\b)[\S\s])+(?=[\s\S]*\bEnd word\b)`

Comment: I think it's because when i try to output the text in variable which is type of IEnumerable<Match> and when I put it in write line activity I type my variable(0).Value.ToString that's why it take only the first line , because vb start from 0 , but how to make it to print the whole if i delete this 0 give error.

Comment: @Swapx You can loop the collection, and for every iteration get the value of the Match

Comment: Hello Yes I just did that used for each activity and for item in collection write line item.toString , but the thing is I need to use this result to replace text in word document and I cannot use this outside the for each where are my word activities. If i try to place the word activities in for each it opens the file n of time per how many matches it have and nothing happens.

Comment: Is there a way to output this outside loop (for each) so I can use it on another place. Or maybe create regex which catch all this with one match , but I guess this wont be possible since we need to ignore H** codes.

Answer (score 1):

I would use this regex:

```
(?<=H\d{3}\b)(?!\+H\d{3})\s*([\w\W]+?)\s*(?=H\d{3}\b|End word)
```

See a demo [here](https://regex101.com/r/uqczO5/1)

Notice that `[.*\w\W\n]` is redundant w.r.t. just `[\w\W]`, because the latter matches any character that is or not a word character (therefore, any character), so it already includes periods, stars and newlines.

Comment: Hello I tested this , but I get only the first H** code text , but not rest of them.

Comment: When I test it out on regex builder it shows all correctly , but when I use it in automation (UiPath) it takes only the first line.

Comment: If you want to skip some portions of text obtaining just one whole match, I don't think you can do that. Tipically, you use the [global mode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12993629) for getting multiple matches and in a second moment you join them togheter.

Comment: No regex is fine I think the way I print data after match is wrong since I'm printing only the first row , but not sure how to print the whole text , like I'm printing only the first match.

Comment: How you can join them ? and have all in one output ?

Comment: Hey I found a way to join all matches in one string.