# Regex including all special characters except space

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a regex which checks all the special characters except space but that looks weird and too long.

```
const specialCharsRegex = new RegExp(/@|#|\$|!|%|&|\^|\*|-|\+|_|=|{|}|\[|\]|\(|\)|~|`|\.|\?|\<|\>|,|\/|:|;|"|'|\\/).

This looks too long and if i use regex (\W) it also includes the space.
Is there is any way i can achieve this?
```

Comment: One thing that would make it shorter is to replace `@|#|\$|!...` with `[@#\$!...]`.

Comment: What do you consider as "space", also tabs, newlines, carriage return? For the latter case, and also to match underscore: [`[^\w\s]+|_+`](https://regex101.com/r/aQeREc/1)

Answer (score 2):

Well you could use:

```
[^\w ]
```

This matches non word characters except for space.  You may blacklist anything else you also might want by adding it to the above character class.

Answer (score 2):

To match anything that [is not](https://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html#negated) a [word character](https://www.regular-expressions.info/shorthand.html) nor a *whitespace character* (cr, lf, ff, space, tab)

```
const specialCharsRegex = new RegExp(/[^\w\s]+|_+/, 'g');
```

[See this demo at regex101](https://regex101.com/r/aQeREc/1) or a [JS replace demo at tio.run](https://tio.run/##jcwxCsIwFMbxvad4ipCE1mYVioviLHS1Wl5jrNXQhKS0RbyP9/BiMUI3F4f38Zb/74Y9OmEb0y37lfdKduBgDeSiNWzQhnvAbP5@LUoo2sriHc8VWsoASBZFQrcuBEaKBtX2itblspZjAFo5QPh3o6H8cCqGwh3jZxnzBEhNWEg5h30e9i@CBCIYE0KSyfi2WslU6Zq61EqjUEj6YyWEMJZ5/wE) (used [`g` flag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12993629/what-is-the-meaning-of-the-g-flag-in-regular-expressions) for all occurrences)

The underscore belongs to *word characters* `[A-Za-z0-9_]` and needs to be matched [separately](https://www.regular-expressions.info/alternation.html).

Answer (score 0):

Try this using a-A-0-9/a-z/A-Z

> `Pattern regex = Pattern.compile("[^A-Za-z0-9]");`