# Simple regex extraction into multiple groups

Tags: javascript, regex

Given this text

```
unit: 100 street: 200 city: 300
```

How do I write a regex that will give this output as different groups in JS. I also need to mention that the text may not contain street or city. It could just be `unit: 100`.

```
group[1] - 100
group[2] - 200
group[3] - 300
```

Where I'm at so far - `unit:\s(.*?)\s(?:.*|$)`

Not sure how to proceed further and get all 3 groups in one regex!

Comment: `/:\s(\d{3})/`?

Comment: Do you have a JSON string?

Comment: It need not be numbers, could be any text.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Not a json string. Its from a log file with a similar format.

Answer (score 1):

You may do this using `split` as well:

```js
const s = 'unit: 100 street: 200 city: 300';

var arr = s.split(/\s*\w+:\s*/).filter(Boolean);

console.log( arr );

//=> ["100", "200", "300"]
```

Here `\s*\w+:\s*` matches 0 or more spaces, followed by 1+ word characters then `:` and 0 or more whitespaces.

Note the `filter(Boolean)` is just used to remove empty elements from resulting array.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a single capture group:

```
[^\s:]+:[^\S\n]*(\S+)
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/y3bGYf/1)

```js
const regex = /[^\s:]+:[^\S\n]*(\S+)/g;
[
  `unit: 100 street: 200 city: 300`,
  `unit: 100`
].forEach(s =>
  console.log(
    Array.from(s.matchAll(regex), m => m[1])
  )
);
```

Or you can use optional nested groups, but the pattern will be longer if you want to use more groups:

```
[^\s:]+:[^\S\n]*(\S+)(?:[^\S\n]+[^\s:]+:[^\S\n]*(\S+)(?:[^\S\n]+[^\s:]+:[^\S\n]*(\S+))?)?
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/BzzRpG/1)

Answer (score 0):

We can use `match()` here:

```js
var input = "unit: 100 street: 200 city: 300";
var matches = input.match(/(?<=: ).*?(?=\s*\w+:|$)/g);
console.log(matches);
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
const rgx = /\D*(\d)(\d)+/g
```

[Regex101](https://regex101.com/r/o23kog/1)

| Segment | Description |
| --- | --- |
| ``` \D* ``` | Zero or more non-digits |
| ``` (\d) ``` | First capture group of a digit |
| ``` (\d)+ ``` | Second capture group of one or more digits |
| ``` g ``` | [`g`lobal flag](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12993629/2813224) |

[`.replace()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) with

```js
"group[$1] - $1$2$2\n"
```

| Segment | Description |
| --- | --- |
| ``` group[$1] ``` | Replace with literal: `group[`, then the first capture group of `(\d)`, and then a literal: `]` |
| ``` - ``` | Then a space, a literal hyphen `-`, and a space |
| ``` $1$2$2\n ``` | Next, the first capture group again: `(\d)`, then the second capture group: `(\d)+` twice, and finally a newline |

**Example A**

```js
const str = `unit: 100 street: 200 city: 300`;
const rgx = /\D*(\d)(\d)+/g;

const res = str.replace(rgx, "group[$1] - $1$2$2\n");
console.log(res);
```

**Note:** The following comment was not considered in **Example A**:

> *It need not be numbers, could be any text."*

The question should have this criteria added and an appropriate example:

```js
'unit: 100 street: Main city: Springfield'
```

Because of this part: `group[?]`, more than one method is needed. See **Example B** for a solution.

**Example B**

```js
const str = 'unit: 100 street: Main city: Springfield';
const rgx = /\b(\w+:) ([\w]+)/g;

const res = str.replace(rgx, "$2")
            .split(' ')
            .map((s, i) => 
              "group["+(i + 1)+"] - "+s).join('\n');

console.log(res);
```