# PostgreSQL - Check column value and update after removing any symbols

Tags: database, postgresql, sql-update

I have large amount of data in a table 'Users'. The 'username' field contains string values but users has input symbols in it e.g. im-a-user, you_are_user, etc.

How can I clean that columns data using SQL query ?

Users:

[image]

I want to clean the values in Username column so that they should look like, imauser, imanotheruser and andmoreuser, etc.

Comment: Honestly I am not sure if its possible to do in SQL.

Comment: Can you show some examples of correct and incorrect values? What do you want to do with incorrect values?

Comment: Possible [duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4428645/1216680)

Comment: show some effort... http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-string.html, http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-matching.html#FUNCTIONS-POSIX-REGEXP

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `regexp_replace()`

```
select id, 
       regexp_replace(lower(username), '[^a-z]', '', 'gi') as clean_user_name
from users;
```